# Make all column editors visible in an ExtJS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I'm trying to figure out how, when I add a new row to my Grid, to make all column editors visible.

Right now, when I add a row to my Grid it's not inherently obvious that the new row is meant to be edited before saving.

Any suggestions as to how to either accomplish making all column editors visible OR is there is a better way to make the new row obviously editable.

EDIT: I found an acceptable solution. I have setup my grid so that, when I add a row, it does a getCount() -1 on the store and then calls startEditing(row, column). This seems acceptable.

Comment: Check out roweditor http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/grid/row-editor.html - might also be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this plugin a shot:

[**http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?79232-EditableGrid-Shows-editors-for-all-cells**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?79232-EditableGrid-Shows-editors-for-all-cells)

Keep in mind that if you have a lot of rows, this **will** affect your performance.

Comment: The grid I need to place this in will have a max of a handful of records so I'm not worried about performance. Anyway, I attempted to use this plugin but I keep getting a "opts is undefined" being thrown inside of ExtJS's code. I have to run on 3.0.0 which is making me think this won't work for me. Thanks anyway.